# my menu bar disappeared and also my sidebar, can't even open terminal too

Tags: 14.04

i am using 14.04 and my menu bar and side bar just disappeared and am having a hard time trying to access anything on my machine, even the terminal. looking forward to your help.

Thank you!

Comment: press Ctrl+Alt+F1. Can you see a terminal? Log into it, and then run the command `unity` in it.

Comment: its still not working?

Answer (score 1):

Log in like normally then after log in press `CTRL+ALT+F1` log in again and type this two commands:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz
setsid unity
```

After this go back to GUI `CTRL+ALT+F7` and see if works

Comment: do i need internet connection for this to work?

Comment: No you don't need internet connection for this.

Comment: on the first command am getting  error: cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY

Comment: and second command get last one has errors too. menu bar and side bar still missing

Comment: Did you first log in to your account via graphical interface? Seems not, sorry i forgot mention this. Log in like normally then after log in hit ctrl+alt+1 log in again and type commands.

Comment: yes i just did as you said, but still nothing.

Comment: Try this commands: `sudo chown -R <your user name>:<your user name> ~/` like for example `sudo chown -R kayz5ive:kayz5ive ~/` (enter your password and wait while done) then `export DISPLAY=:0` and `sudo mv ~/.Xauthority ~/.Xauthority.backup` reboot, login and try

Comment: it didn't work man

Comment: Did you try this answers [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)? If you find something that help you let me know

Comment: hie i used this from the link and it worked. "Press Ctrl+Alt+T for a terminal and run ccsm, then re-enable your 'Unity' plugin." Ctrl+Alt+T worked for i had created a terminal shortcut on my desktop.Thank you very much! :)